# Асинхронные запросы в ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kotlin

При попытке выполнить два запроса к эластику вместе, один запрос отклоняется с ошибкой контроля версий

```
{"error":{"reason":"[operation][wtWubh3DHE2TFpNsL]: version conflict, current version [5] is different than the one provided [4]","index_uuid":"jsbbwKwJSeSCJcgUBX-FeQ","index":"operations","shard":"3","type":"version_conflict_engine_exception","root_cause":[{"reason":"[operation][wtWubh3DHE2TFpNsL]: version conflict, current version [5] is different than the one provided [4]","index_uuid":"jsbbwKwJSeSCJcgUBX-FeQ","index":"operations","shard":"3","type":"version_conflict_engine_exception"}]},"status":409}
```

Второй проходит удачно:

```
{"result":"updated","_shards":{"total":2,"failed":0,"successful":1},"_index":"operations","_type":"operation","_id":"wtWubh3DHE2TFpNsL","_version":5}
```

Пробовал добавлять ?refresh в конце запроса, но это тоже не помогает. Код:

```
thread {
    val json_a = JSONObject().put("script", "ctx._source.thread_in_work+=1")
    val a = Unirest.post("http://localhost:9200/operations/operation/wtWubh3DHE2TFpNsL/_update")
            .body(json_a.toString())
    println(a.asJson().body)
}
thread {
    val json_a = JSONObject().put("script", "ctx._source.thread_in_work+=1")
    val a = Unirest.post("http://localhost:9200/operations/operation/wtWubh3DHE2TFpNsL/_update")
            .body(json_a.toString())
    println(a.asJson().body)
}
```

Я знаю, что здесь можно сделать +2, но надо увеличивать на один при поступлении запроса на сервер, а запросов поступает несколько одновременно. Поэтому такой код позволяет воссоздать ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Система версий elasticsearch существует для реализации оптимистичной блокировки. Это значит, что если кто-то иной, нежели текущий клиент, успел обновить документ между чтением и записью, движок отклонит такое обновление, что и происходит - предполагается, что в этом случае клиент просто повторит запрос, и рано или поздно клиент "протащит" свое обновление. Таким образом, эластик просто просит вас повторить операцию (потому что иначе он не может гарантировать корректность выполнения, даже с таким простым инкрементом), и вам нужно либо просто засунуть операцию в while-цикл, либо воспользоваться параметром [`retry_on_conflict`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/docs-update.html#_parameters_2), который сделает то же самое на стороне ES.

В то же время хочу отметить, что существует официальный java-клиент для ES, который наверняка можно подцепить в kotlin и с которым такие вещи будут обрабатываться гораздо проще (надо будет ловить не HTTP код 409, а вполне конкретное исключение), и что ES не стоит использовать в качестве хранилища данных - он пока не предоставляет достаточных гарантий, и, потому что в первую очередь он является поисковым движком, подобные проблемы не являются главным приоритетом команды (это не значит, что они над ними не работают - просто это совсем не тривиальные вещи, на которые нужно потратить много ресурсов, [ссылка на документацию](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html)). Другими словами, при определенных условиях вы имеет возможность получать неверные значения из счетчика, который обновляете, равно как и терять обновления этого счетчика.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Пока использую retry_on_conflict - все работает. А какие есть решения для гарантирования корректной работы моего счетчика, в случае появления проблем?

Comment: @Валентин любое решение, которое гарантирует порядок операций (линеаризуемость), это может быть SQL-база, etcd, consul или riak при правильном применении. Строго говоря, с описанной проблемой вы можете никогда и не столкнуться, и она скорее всего невозможна при работе с кластером elasticsearch из одного узла, но я был обязан предупредить.

Comment: еще раз спасибо. Буду внимательно наблюдать